# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '08/22/1954' to data type int

Tags: vb.net, date, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I am trying to write **`stored procedure`** within my **`sql command`** as shown:

```
Dim tdate As String = Me.PresentDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")

myCommand As New SqlCommand("select c.description as 'provider',b.lastname,
b.firstname, b.middleinitial,convert(varchar(10),b.dob,101) as DOB,
b.chartID,b.sex, d.businessname,d.businessfax from patientappointmentbase as a, 
patientlistbase as b,resourcebase as c, locationbase as d where convert(varchar(10),
a.starttime,101) = " & tdate & " 
and a.patientid = b.patientid and a.resourceid = c.resourceid and 
a.locationid = d.locationid order by provider, lastname, firstname", myConnection)
```

and when I run this code I'm getting the error as

***`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '08/22/1954' to data type int.`***

Comment: Are you sure that this message refers to the 'tdate' variable?. I see another convert and the value in the message seems to be a DOB not a starttime

Comment: @steve-yes...i'm sure as I have given the specific date instead of tdate and it worked pretty well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two primary problems.

The first problem is that the date is being inlined to SQL so that the SQL you are executing looks like:

```
select ... where convert(varchar(10), a.starttime,101) = 07-07-2013
```

This is not valid SQL, so you need to wrap the date parameter in single quotes, i.e.

```
... where convert(varchar(10), a.starttime,101) = '" & tdate & "' and ...
```

If you wrap it in double-quotes and you have QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set to on, SQL Server will attempt to interpret it as a column name.

The second problem is that you are using two different date formats to compare. Convert using a style of 101 yields a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy. However, you are using a format of mm-dd-yyyy.

This means you are asking SQL server to compare "07/07/2013" with "07-07-2013" which will never be the same. The easiest fix is to change the date format of tdate to match SQL Server's:

```
Dim tdate As String = Me.PresentDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenated SQL string looks like

```
convert(varchar(10), a.starttime,101) = 08/22/1954
```

That's a sequence of division operations that results in a number, not a date.

You want to create a date literal by wrapping the value in quotes.
(or, better yet, use parameters)

Comment: I have used inside double quotes....and I have even tried by using @Date and passed the date parameter eventhough I have the same problem.